# Can not validate authorization code in WSO2 IS 5.2.0 Cluster mode

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I recently updated my environment from WSO2 IS 5.0.0 to WSO2 IS 5.2.0. My environment consists of 2 machines that are creating a cluster (using the WKA membership scheme and Load Balancer(AWS ELB) with sticky session enabled). I am using MySQL(not the default H2 database). The machines on which the IS is deployed are Windows Server 2012 R2 (EC2 AWS machines).

I ensured that the "IS_HOME\repository\conf\datasources\master-datasources.xml" is configured the same way on both machines and that they are using the exact same MySQL data sources. Also I am sure that the correct database is referenced in user-mgt.xml and identity.xml.
I have two worker nodes under AWS ELB as mentioned above. When the cluster was configured the following instructions were used:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+Identity+Server+5.1.0

I have application which is using the clientID and clientSecret of one of the service providers. I am using the authorization_code grant type. When I try to login in my application and I am redirected to NODE1 I receive authorization code and I am trying to get access token by calling:  https://URL/oauth2/token?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URId&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTH_CODE.
If this request is processed by NODE1 I receive access token and everything is fine. However if the mentioned above request is processed by NODE2, I receive the following:
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Error when validating an authorization code"
}
I am able to see the generated authorization code in the IDN_OAUTH2_AUTHORIZATION_CODE table. I double checked that the machine clocks are synchronized and are using NTP, but I am not able to validate authorization code generated by NODE1 through NODE2 and vice versa.
If I am running single node configuration, no such issues is reproduced.
I am not seeing any errors in wso2carbon.log regarding this issue.
I have patch0481 applied to my system.

Could this be some sort of configuration issue? If so in which configuration files I should take a look?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming you have worked with identity service-stub. Can you tried the same thing with service-stub "org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.stub". The information you have provided is very limited. Can you enable trace and include your logs.